# Derive two hours time blocks from start and end time fields

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table

I have a table in Microsoft Access that has a list of volunteers for an event.  The table contains fields such as name, phone number, etc.  There are three additional fields; Assignment which describes what activity the volunteer will be assigned to.  For example, parking, front gate, ticket Booth, etc.  The two other fields, start and end time describe when a volunteer is able to work.

Is it possible to write a query - maybe some sort of pivot table -  that has 2 hours time slots as the row header and some sort of true/false value if the time slot has been filled for the assignment?  The event is from 6am to 6pm.

For example:

```
Assignment | 0600 | 0800 | 1000 | 1200 | 1400  | 1600 
Parking    |  X   |  o   |   X  |  X   |   X   |   X  
TicketBooth|  o   |  o   |   X  |  o   |   X   |   o
```

I'm trying to group volunteers by their assignment and derive two hour time blocks from the start and end time of each volunteer and generate a report which would allow the event coordinator to easily distinguish whether they would need to add a volunteer to the assignment.

The volunteers table structure looks like this:

```
FirstName | LastName | Assignment   | StartTime | EndTime
Joe       | Smith    | Parking      | 1000      | 1800
Jessica   | Anderson | Parking      | 0600      | 0800
Ryan      | Webber   | TicketBooth  | 1000      | 1200
Michael   | Flent    | TicketBooth  | 1400      | 1600
```

Is it possible to generate a query to get the results shown in the example above given the table structure?  If not, what would I need to modify?

Comment: I'm looking at your data, and then your example, but I see no data regarding the actual volunteers?

Comment: I was thinking that the group by clause would be used somehow and then the actual volunteers would be irrelevant, but again I am open to all suggestion on how to accomplish this task.  I'll go ahead and edit the question.  Thanks

Comment: It's just better to be explicit :)

Comment: You're definitely right.  I added the table structure to the example above.

Comment: What are the datatypes of your StartTime and EndTime fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so given your sample data, a Pivot table is not ideal because the lack of a table/join table with times and who can work when, etc.

So, I created a function that returns `"o"` or `"x"` depending on if someone's availability fits into the time slots you've provided us an example with. The only bad thing is that you have to manually create a column for each time slot. That would have been the nice thing with a Pivot table.

This could have been done using an `IIf()` as well. Here's a quick example of that:

```
SELECT volunteers.Names,
       volunteers.Assignment, 
       IIf(1800>=[Start] And 1800<=[End],"Can Work","Can't") AS 1800
FROM volunteers;
```

Anyway, here's the function (I didn't handle any errors) :

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function IsAvailable(time, starttime, endtime) As String

Dim AvailableTime, StartingTime, EndingTime As Integer

AvailableTime = time
StartingTime = starttime
EndingTime = endtime

If AvailableTime >= StartingTime And AvailableTime <= EndingTime Then
    IsAvailable = "o"
Else
    IsAvailable = "x"
End If

End Function
```

How you can use it with a query:

```
SELECT volunteers.Names, 
       volunteers.Assignment, 
       IsAvailable(600,[Start],[End]) AS 0600, 
       IsAvailable(800,[Start],[End]) AS 0800, 
       IsAvailable(1000,[Start],[End]) AS 1000, 
       IsAvailable(1200,[Start],[End]) AS 1200, 
       IsAvailable(1400,[Start],[End]) AS 1400, 
       IsAvailable(1600,[Start],[End]) AS 1600, 
       IsAvailable(1800,[Start],[End]) AS 1800
FROM volunteers;
```

Visualized:

[image]

Note: I used `Start` and `End` for my column names in my table, so you would have to change `[Start]` and `[End]`, respectively.

Also, I don't personally think this is the best solution. I think if you knew this data was required to be in this format I would have probably designed my database for it, but this is kind of a crude work-around.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will give this a try shortly.  When you say you would have designed your database for this, what do you mean?  Use date time fields instead?

Comment: Well, I would have had a table that stored time options (every 2 hours in your case) and a 'join table' where I would have a record for every Time Option that someone was able to work.

Answer (score 2):

I made a time blocks table with Date/Time fields for the start and end of
each block.  Then `CROSS JOIN`ed that with the table which contains the volunteers' assignments, and used it as the data source for a cross tab query.

This is the result set from the query below ...

[image: CrossTab query result set]

Notes:

1. I used a number (instead of "X") in the scheduled time blocks.  That could be useful if you ever have more than one volunteer scheduled for the same assignment at the same time ... either intentionally or by mistake.
2. In my *assignments* table, both *StartTime* and *EndTime* are Date/Time datatype.  If yours are text, this general approach can still work, but you'll have to adjust the query.

This is the query ...

```sql
TRANSFORM Count(q.block_start) AS CountOfBlock_start
SELECT q.Assignment
FROM
    (
        SELECT a.Assignment, tb.block_start
        FROM assignments AS a, time_blocks AS tb
        WHERE
                tb.block_start >= [a].[StartTime] 
            AND tb.block_end   <= [a].[EndTime]
    ) AS q
GROUP BY q.Assignment
PIVOT Format(q.block_start, 'hhnn')
    IN ('0600','0800','1000','1200','1400','1600');
```

This is my *time_blocks* table ...

```
block_start block_end
----------- -----------
 6:00:00 AM  8:00:00 AM
 8:00:00 AM 10:00:00 AM
10:00:00 AM 12:00:00 PM
12:00:00 PM  2:00:00 PM
 2:00:00 PM  4:00:00 PM
 4:00:00 PM  6:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Very nice! I had created my own time table as well but figured I could have made a lot more work for myself :P. Nice answer! +1